# JQuery Datepicker not working in Contentpage ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Datapicker is working fine without Master Page but when i use Master page and content page, it is not working in Content Page.  I am using the following code for Datapicker in Master page and Content page.

In the Head of Master page, I have the following code.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
             $("#<%=txtFromDate.ClientID %>").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
             $("#<%=txtToDate.ClientID %>").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });                     
         });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
In Content Page I am writing the following code.

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
             $("#<%=txtFromDate.ClientID %>").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
             $("#<%=txtToDate.ClientID %>").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });                     
         });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">


<table>
    <tr>
                <td>
                    From Date
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFromDate" runat="server" Width="220" 

ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
                    <span id="spnPDate" class="err" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    To Date
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtToDate" runat="server" Width="220" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
                    <span id="spnEDate" class="err" />
                </td>
            </tr>
   </table>
</asp:Content>
```

How can I use Datapicker in Content Page?

Comment: Please show us the html code when you do view source on the web page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> use this I tested it

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
             $("#<%=txtFromDate.ClientID %>").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
             $("#<%=txtToDate.ClientID %>").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });                     
         });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">


<table>
    <tr>
                <td>
                    From Date
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFromDate" runat="server" Width="220" 

ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
                    <span id="spnPDate" class="err" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    To Date
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtToDate" runat="server" Width="220" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
                    <span id="spnEDate" class="err" />
                </td>
            </tr>
   </table>
</asp:Content>
```

[image]

Comment: "Das Steuerelement txtFromDate vom Typ TextBox muss in einem Formulartag mit runat=server positioniert werden." this error

Comment: if I write between form tag, then it does not work either